# Accessing a database through Rails model from a seperate Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application with a database (PostgreSQL using ActiveRecord)

In a separate directory on the same server I have a Ruby script.

How can I, from the Ruby script, reach the Rails database through one of my Rails models?

---

I have seen that it is possible to require ActiveRecord and pass in the database details, but from what I understand I would need to rebuild the model, which means a lot of repetition of validations, methods, etc. Instead I'd like to somehow use the model that's already in place.

Comment: Why not use a rake task?

Comment: In what way? From what I understand rake tasks live in the Rails app, under lib/tasks. My Ruby script is completely separate from the Rails app.

Comment: They do, but you're trying to interact with the rails app.  So I'd use a rake task

Comment: Is this a one time task? Or will you have to solve this problem more often? A rake task in the mentionend directory is easiest way by far. If you want to separate your tasks from your app create a Rails engine with only your models in it, and require it from your app and your script.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that has the behaviour I was looking for, and am posting it as an answer for anyone who comes across this question at a later date.

Setting `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "production"` and then simply requiring the `environment.rb` file (with the appropriate path) in the Ruby script solves the issue very nicely.

This is similar to the answer provided by @MurifoX, but saves you having to re-declare the DB connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try using rails runner. According to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner

> runner runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively. For
>   instance:

```
bin/rails runner "Model.long_running_method"
```

In my experience this works nicely to run scripts that rely on Active Record and more.

Add the -e switch to the command to force the use of your production database connection:

```
bin/rails runner -e staging "Model.long_running_method"
```

Add any other environment variables that may be required to complete the database connection. If you use the Devise gem, you will also need to pass in a secret to allow the Devise initializations to complete. Other gems may equally need some assistance to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` to pass the relative path to your model, and then instatiate it a use.

```
require '/path/to/your/model/inside/your/app'

model = Model.new
```

For the connection, if you are using `postgresql`, you can use the `PGconn` class from the `pg` gem like this:

```
@connection = PGconn.open(
  :user => 'postgres', 
  :password => 'password', 
  :host => 'host', 
  :dbname => 'dbname')
```